# How do I add resources to my AutoIt exe file?

Tags: autoit

I want to include a few txt files to my AutoIT application.

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_Field=#AutoIt3Wrapper_icon|C:\Scripts\AutoIt\HelpDeskIT\images\helpdesk_icon.ico
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_File_Add=C:\Scripts\AutoIt\HelpDeskIT\Instructions.txt
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_File_Add=C:\Scripts\AutoIt\HelpDeskIT\reportaproblem.txt
```

but it's not being added to my exe file. (when I launch the app it can't find the files)

Answer (score 3):

From the SciTE4AutoIt3 help (under Extra Utilities --> AutoIt3Wrapper)...

> **Adding a file:**
>
> Files are stored in the RT_RCDATA section and are usually stored byte
>   for byte.  If the section value is set to -10 (RT_RCDATA is internally
>   evaluated as 10) then the file is compressed before being added:
>
> ```
> #AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_File_Add=file_name, RT_RCDATA     : UNCOMPRESSED 
> #AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_File_Add=file_name, 10            ; UNCOMPRESSED 
> #AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_File_Add=file_name, -10           ; COMPRESSED
> ```
>
> When the file is required it can be extracted using this code. Set the
>   $isCompressed parameter to match the Res_File_Add directive:
>
> ```
> #include <WinAPIRes.au3> 
> #include <WinAPIInternals.au3> 
>
> Func _FileInstallFromResource($sResName, $sDest, $isCompressed = False, $iUncompressedSize = Default) 
>     Local $bBytes = _GetResourceAsBytes($sResName, $isCompressed, $iUncompressedSize) 
>     If @error Then Return SetError(@error, 0, 0) 
>     FileDelete($sDest) 
>     FileWrite($sDest, $bBytes) 
> EndFunc 
>
> Func _GetResourceAsBytes($sResName, $isCompressed = False, $iUncompressedSize = Default) 
>     Local $hMod = _WinAPI_GetModuleHandle(Null) 
>     Local $hRes = _WinAPI_FindResource($hMod, 10, $sResName) 
>     If @error Or Not $hRes Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0) 
>     Local $dSize = _WinAPI_SizeOfResource($hMod, $hRes) 
>     If @error Or Not $dSize Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0) 
>     Local $hLoad = _WinAPI_LoadResource($hMod, $hRes) 
>     If @error Or Not $hLoad Then Return SetError(3, 0, 0) 
>     Local $pData = _WinAPI_LockResource($hLoad) 
>     If @error Or Not $pData Then Return SetError(4, 0, 0) 
>     Local $tBuffer = DllStructCreate("byte[" & $dSize & "]") 
>     _WinAPI_MoveMemory(DllStructGetPtr($tBuffer), $pData, $dSize) 
>     If $isCompressed Then 
>         Local $oBuffer 
>        _WinAPI_LZNTDecompress($tBuffer, $oBuffer, $iUncompressedSize) 
>         If @error Then Return SetError(5, 0, 0) 
>         $tBuffer = $oBuffer 
>     EndIf 
>     Return DllStructGetData($tBuffer, 1) 
> EndFunc 
>
> Func _WinAPI_LZNTDecompress(ByRef $tInput, ByRef $tOutput, $iUncompressedSize = Default) 
>     ; if no uncompressed size given, use 16x the input buffer 
>     If $iUncompressedSize = Default Then $iUncompressedSize = 16 * DllStructGetSize($tInput) 
>     Local $tBuffer, $ret 
>     $tOutput = 0 
>     $tBuffer = DllStructCreate("byte[" & $iUncompressedSize & "]") 
>     If @error Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0) 
>     $ret = DllCall("ntdll.dll", "long", "RtlDecompressBuffer", "ushort", 2, "struct*", $tBuffer, "ulong", $iUncompressedSize, "struct*", $tInput, "ulong", DllStructGetSize($tInput), "ulong*", 0) 
>     If @error Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0) 
>     If $ret[0] Then Return SetError(3, $ret[0], 0) 
>     $tOutput = DllStructCreate("byte[" & $ret[6] & "]") 
>     If Not _WinAPI_MoveMemory(DllStructGetPtr($tOutput), DllStructGetPtr($tBuffer), $ret[6]) Then 
>         $tOutput = 0 
>         Return SetError(4, 0, 0) 
>     EndIf 
>     Return $ret[6] 
> EndFunc
> ```