# Include files from directory (at run-time)

Tags: file, include, autoit

I want to include files from a folder in my script (I tried to Google but can't seem to find any way to do this with AutoIt). Example of what I want to achieve:

```
LoadFiles()

Func LoadFiles()
    $FL = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir&"\Test\", "*")    
    $X=1

    Do    
        #include $FL[$X]  <== How ?    
        $X=$X+1 
    Until $X=$FL[0]
EndFunc
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

In order to include a file(s) in your compiled script, you need `FileInstall`.

```
FileInstall ( "source", "dest" [, flag = 0] )
```

- `source` The source path of the file to compile. This must be a literal string; it cannot be a variable or the result of a function call. It can be a relative path (using .\ or ..\ in the path) to the source file (.au3).
- `dest` The destination path of the file with trailing backslash if only the directory is used. This can be a variable.
- `flag` [optional] this flag determines whether to overwrite files if they already exist:
  $FC_NOOVERWRITE (0) = (default) do not overwrite existing files
  $FC_OVERWRITE (1) = overwrite existing files

Another way is [adding the files as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838054/how-do-i-add-resources-to-my-autoit-exe)

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon! There isn't currently a good way to do what you're asking. I've been working on building a UDF to do what you'd like, but I've been running into a couple of issues with it. I have a working prototype but there are some bugs in it. First things first, download this script and call it _includeDir.au3.

**_includeDir.au3**

```
#CS
        Name: _includeDir.au3
        Developer: Timothy Bomer
        Copyright: Amarok Studios LLC 2016
        Version: 1.0
        Description:
            The purpose of this UDF is to dynamically include all files inside of a folder.
            It works for the most part, but I am still working on a couple of bugs.
#CE


#Include <File.au3>


Global $mainUDF = "IncludeDirUDF"
Global $includeLib = $mainUDF & "\" & "loadIncludes.au3"
Global $tempLib = $mainUDF & "\" & "lib.txt"
Global $includeRewrite = $mainUDF & "\rewrite.au3"
Global $iDirHolder = ""


Func _includeDir($iDir, $lineToInc = 1, $restart = True)
    If (checkInclude()) = 1 Then
        FileDelete($tempLib)
        return
    EndIf
    If NOT (FileExists($iDir)) Then
        MsgBox(16,"Directory Doesn't Exists | _includeDir","The directory " & $iDir & " does not exist!")
        return 0
    EndIf
    $iDirHolder = $iDir
    initializeCheck()
    ; MsgBox(0,"Include Directory", "Attempting to include: " & $iDir)
    populateLib($iDir)
    populateIncLib()
    finalize($lineToInc, $restart)
EndFunc





Func checkInclude()
    FileOpen(@ScriptName, 0)
    For $i = 1 to _FileCountLines(@ScriptName)
        $checkLine = FileReadLine(@ScriptName, $i)
        If ($checkLine = '#Include "IncludeDirUDF\loadIncludes.au3"') Then
        return 1
        EndIf
    Next
EndFunc

; START Initialize Check
Func initializeCheck()
    ; MsgBox(0,"Checking. . .", "Is this initialized?")
    If (FileExists($mainUDF)) Then
        If NOT (FileExists($includeLib)) Then
            isError(2)
            return
        EndIf
        
        ; MsgBox(0,"Initialized","The UDF has been initialized")
    Else
        isError(1)
        return
    EndIf
EndFunc
; END Initialize Check

; START Library Population
Func populateLib($iDir = $iDirHolder)
    ; MsgBox(0,"Populating","Attempting to populate the library")
    If (FileExists($tempLib)) Then
        ; MsgBox(0,"Temp File Found","The temporary library file has been found. Attempting to populate.")
        $tLibCont = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir & "\" & $iDir & "\", "*")
        $iDirSize = $tLibCont[0]
        ; MsgBox(0,"Size of Included Directory", $iDir & " contains " & $iDirSize & " files to include!")
        $writeLib = FileOpen($tempLib, 1)
        While $iDirSize > 0
            FileWriteLine($writeLib, '#Include "..\' & $iDir & '\' & $tLibCont[$iDirSize] & '"')
            $iDirSize -= 1
        WEnd
        FileClose($writeLib)
    Else
        isError(3)
        return
    EndIf
EndFunc
; END Library Population

; START Include Library Population
Func populateIncLib()
    ; MsgBox(0,"Rewriting. . .", "Attempting to re-write the include library")
    #CS
    If (FileExists($includeLib)) Then
        FileDelete($includeLib)
        _FileCreate($includeLib)
    EndIf
    #CE
    FileOpen($tempLib, 0)
    For $i = 1 to _FileCountLines($tempLib)
        $line = FileReadLine($tempLib, $i)
        $reWriteLib = FileOpen($includeLib, 9)
        FileWriteLine($reWriteLib, $line)
        FileClose($reWriteLib)
    Next
    FileClose($tempLib)
EndFunc
; END Include Library Population

; START Finalize
Func finalize($lineToInc, $restart)
    _FileWriteToLine(@ScriptName, $lineToInc, '#Include "IncludeDirUDF\loadIncludes.au3"', False)
    If ($restart = True) Then
        runFile(@ScriptName)
    EndIf
    exit
    return
EndFunc




Func runFile($rFile)
    $file_loc = $rFile
 
    If @Compiled = 1 Then
         $file_exe = FileGetShortName(@AutoItExe & ' /AutoIt3ExecuteScript "' & $file_loc & '"')
         Run($file_exe)
    Else
         $file_au3 = FileGetShortName($file_loc)
         Run(@AutoItExe & " " & $file_au3, "", @SW_HIDE)
     EndIf
EndFunc







; START Error Reporting
Func isError($eFlag = "", $eMessage = "There was an error!")
    If ($eFlag = "") Then
        ; MsgBox(16,"ERROR", $eMessage)
        Exit
    EndIf
    
    If ($eFlag = 1) Then
        ; MsgBox(16,"Not Initialized","This UDF has not been initialized")
        DirCreate($mainUDF)
        Sleep(250)
        initializeCheck()
        return
    ElseIf ($eFlag = 2) Then
        ; MsgBox(16,"Missing File","Missing the include library!")
        _FileCreate($includeLib)
        initializeCheck()
        return
    
    ElseIf ($eFlag = 3) Then
        ; MsgBox(16,"Missing File", "Missing the temporary library! Creating it now!",3)
        _FileCreate($tempLib)
        populateLib()
        return
    EndIf
EndFunc
; END Error Reporting
```

To use this UDF, include the file with:

> ## Include "_includeDir.au3"

Next, call the function by following the below format.

> _includeDir("Directory to Include", $lineToIncludeOn, $restart)

The directory to include would be the name of the directory with all of the files you're trying to include.

The $lineToIncludeOn specifies what line of the script the #Include will be written on. This is an optional parameter, and will default to line 1.

Lastly, $restart specifies if the script needs to be restarted or not. Sadly, the biggest bug is that the script needs to be restarted in order for the UDF to include all of the files. Which probably takes away the useful functionality of the entire script. This is an optional parameter, by default, it will be set to True and automatically restart the script.

---

Here's an example.

**INSIDE OF WORKING DIRECTORY**

> Includes Folder
>
> Example.au3
>
> _includeDir.au3

**INSIDE OF Includes Folder**

> One.au3
>
> Two.au3
>
> Three.au3
>
> Four.au3
>
> Five.au3

### One.au3

```
$oneVar = "First variable"
```

### Two.au3

```
$twoVar = "Second variable"
```

### Three.au3

```
$threeVar = "Third variable"
```

### Four.au3

```
$fourVar = "Fourth variable"
```

### Five.au3

```
$fiveVar = "Fifth variable"
```

So, we are going to try to include One.au3, Two.au3, Three.au3, Four.au3, and Five.au3 into Example.au3.

### Example.au3

```
; Exclude the numbers before the code. It's there just to show you the line the code is written on.

(1) #Include "_includeDir.au3"

(2)

(3) _includeDir("Includes Folder")

(4) MsgBox(0,"Included Variables","Variable One: " & $oneVar & @CRLF & "Variable Two: " & $twoVar & @CRLF & "Variable Three: " & $threeVar & @CRLF & "Variable Four: " & $fourVar & @CRLF & "Variable Five: " & $fiveVar)
```

This will add the line:

```
#Include "IncludeDirUDF\loadIncludes.au3"
```

to line one of Examples.au3, then restart Example.au3 to display the variables from the included files. If you changed the files inside of the Included Files directory, you will need to remove the #Include line for the loadIncludes.au3, and delete the folder that was generated. (IncludeDirUDF).

Let's say you don't want the #Include to be written to line one of Example.au3... To specify what line you want it to be written to, simply add the next parameter to the function call. For example, we want to write it to line 5 of Example.au3, we would use this:

```
_includeDir("Includes Folder", 5)
```

The last parameter is the restart parameter. This specifies if Example.au3 should be restarted after the directory is included. It is set to True by default. If you want Example.au3 to exit and stay terminated, simply add False to the end of the function call.

```
_includeDir("Includes Folder", 5, False)
```

In order to do what you're trying to do, the best way to use this would be to put it at the top of your Example.au3 (or whatever your script is) right underneath the includes. The reason for this is because it will auto-restart your script if when it generates the library and it could cause an error if it's not at the top. I hope this poorly written UDF helps you out! Let me know if there's something it's not doing that you need it to do. If not, let me know and I will fix it! Happy programming my friend! If this is too hard to follow, see my more detailed demonstration on the official AutoIt forum [HERE](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/185192-include-full-directory/)

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it if anyone have the same issue ..
Only thing IncludeList.au3 have to exsist in the directory before you run the script or you will get include error

```
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <File.au3>


; Delete Old IncludeList.au3
If FileExists("IncludeList.au3") Then
FileDelete("IncludeList.au3")
EndIf

; Get Files From Dir
$IL = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir&"\Functions\", "*")

; Create New IncludeList.au3
$FH = FileOpen("IncludeList.au3", $FO_APPEND)

; Check For Errors
If @error <> 1 or @error <> 4 Then

; Loop True Files In Dir
For $FC = 1 To UBound($IL)-1 Step +1

; Write New #Include '.\Function\FilesToInclude.au3'
FileWrite($FH, "#Include '.\Functions\"&$IL[$FC]&"'"& @CRLF)

Next
EndIf
; Close File Handler
FileClose($FH)

; Include All The Files In Directory True IncludeList We Created
#include "IncludeList.au3" 

; And Now You Can Call Any Functions From The Scripts From That Directory
```